# Nominatim UK for geocoding: problem with house numbers

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, nominatim, address-parsing

I am testing a few random "addresses string" with Nominatim (https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/). It looks ok to find the street, but it doesn't look able to pick the right coordinates on the same street for different house numbers (instead done correctly by Google Maps), and place the point in the middle of the street.

Is this a known limitation of Nominatim or can be worked around?

Answer (score 1):

Nominatim uses Open Street Map data which does not always contain house numbers or names, in which case where Nominatim can't find a number on the street, or named location, it will return a location for the street as you have found. More information is available in the [Nominatim Wiki Page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Address_lookup)

Googles Geocoder on the other hand does have some knowledge of house numbers, in part as Google have been [geocoding Streetview images](http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/16/googles-new-street-view-image-recognition-algorithm-can-beat-most-captchas/) (partly through Captchas).